# Recursive Fibonacci algorithm with variant

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, fibonacci

I've implemented a traditional fibonacci recursion related with the reproduction of a population of rabbits in python2.7

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n is 0 or n is 1: return 1
    else: return (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2))
```

This code computes the population if exactly one month after two rabbits mate, they produce one male and one female rabbit. Now I need to modify the code to compute the population if every pair of reproduction-age rabbits produces a litter of k rabbit pairs (instead of only 1 pair). How can I do this in a recursive way? What is the most appropriate model for the recursive case?

Comment: What is the mathematical recurrence relation? Is it `f(0) = f(1) = k`, and `f(n+2) = ((n+2)choose k) * (f(n+1) + f(n))`?

Comment: That is not the correct model, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well let's try and derive the sequence, which is also known as a multi-nacci sequence of order k. See this [paper](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/26-4/levine.pdf) for some more interesting tidbits.

The basic rule is the same: it takes 1 month to for a pair to mature

Therefore at:

Month 0: 1 pair exists (young)

Month 1: 1 pair exists (adult)

Month 2: 1 pair exists (adult) + k pairs exist (young) = 1 + k total

Month 3: 1 + k pairs exist (adult) + k pairs exist (young) = 1 + 2k total

Month 4: 1 + 2k pairs exist (adult) + k (1 + k) pairs exist (young) = 1 + k(3 + k) total

Month 5: 1 + 3k + k^2 pairs exist (adult) + k (1 + 2k) pairs exist (young) = 1 + k(4 + 3k) total

and so on...

---

Notice that with each month, the total number of rabbit pairs is k * number of adults (which are two generations old) + number of young pairs (which are 1 generation old). Therefore the amount of rabbits at generation n is k * number of rabbits at generation n - 2 (as these are now all adults) + number of rabbits at generation n - 1

**Mathematically**: f(0) = 1, f(1) = 1, f(n) = f(n-1) + k * f(n-2).

**Code:**

```
def fibnum(n, k):
    if n < 0:
         raise ValueError("n must be a positive value")
    if n is 0 or n is 1:
        return 1
    else: 
        return (fibnum(n-1, k) + k * fibnum(n-2, k))
```

---

Notes:

- This code is 0-based: so 5th month is n=4 and so on.
- **WARNING:** this sequence grows ridiculously fast with larger k (so calculating fibnum(100, 100) may take a while). Memoization is advised to provide a significant speedup for increasing n.

**Update:** Changed code to accept k as a parameter, and cleaned up my code formatting a bit. Added reference to multinacci sequence

Comment: Is not working, k-fibNum with n=5 and k=3 must return 19 but your implementation is returning 40

Comment: def fibonacci(n,k):
    if n is 0 or n is 1: return 1
    else: return fibonacci(n-1,k) + k*fibonacci(n-2,k)

Comment: You have an off by 1 error. I have my months 0-based, while you use 1-based. My function with n=4 and k=3 does return 19. I will modify my function to accept k as a parameter instead of having it defined externally.

Comment: But Im you using the same if statement used by k-fibnum. BTW your mathematical argument is excellent, congrats

Comment: By "you have an off by 1 error" I don't mean the code is wrong, I'm saying that your interpretation of the results is wrong. N=5 and k=3 should return 40 in my case, as it refers to the 6th month, while the value of 19 refers to the 5th month (or n=4).